# Colab/Jupyter/Python: How to read uploaded file

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I am familiar with Python, but trying to use it in google drive/colab. I cannot seem to load an image with the code below (the file is in the same folder as the code/notebook). Any ideas?

```
import cv2 
file1 = 'image1.JPG'
image = cv2.imread(file1)
if(image):
  print("File present")
else:
  print("File not present")
```

Comment: where you uploaded the image colab or google drive? try to print `os.listdir()` and check for the file in result

Comment: Thanks. The result of listdir() is this: ['.config', 'sample_data']. It doesn't seem that the code and the uploaded files are in the same directory - not sure why?

Comment: it means the file is not uploaded? did you able to see the file in sidebar

Comment: I see the .ipynb and the image file in the same directory in google drive (My Drive> Colab Notebooks), but the listed folder contents don't show the image file. So, the .ipynb and .jpg are in different folders even though they show up in the same folder in google drive.

Comment: where you uploaded the file colab or google drive?

Comment: I figured it out. The file has to be dragged/dropped into the side bar.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your image is actually there, one way to do this is with the built in IPython library

```py
from IPython.display import Image
Image('file1.JPG')
```

I ran your code above with a working image and got an error due to the ambiguity of checking the existence of the numpy array:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Taking these suggestions into consideration, and changing your code slightly with a definitely working url link gave the desired output:

```py
import cv2 
file1 = 'file1.JPG'
image = cv2.imread(file1)
print(type(image))
if image.any():
  print("File present")
else:
  print("File not present")

# Returns "File present"
```